# remove software on Kubuntu with apt command

Tags: apt, kubuntu

I know this is a funny question but I am a new user and I want to know how to use the `apt` command to remove software in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove software, you can use `remove`. For example:

```
sudo apt remove tableplus
```

This will still leave configuration files behind, though. If you want to *completely* remove an application that was installed via `apt`, you can do this:

```
sudo apt purge tableplus
```

Hope this answers your question.